# ¿Cómo realizar consultas a páginas externas desde una base de MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux, apache

Quiero saber si en la Base de datos puede crearse un campo desde donde se realice una consulta a un sitio externo.

Ejemplo:
Desde la web muestro productos de terceros, registrados en mi base de datos, con cierto precio "$X.-" el cual se debería modificar si en el sitio de origen lo aumentan o rebajan.

Entorno de trabajo:
CentOs / Apache / PHP / MySQL

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si el sitio está fuera de tu infraestructura no puedes, lo que tienes que hacer es programar la integración con el sitio de modo que al consultar este artículo se llame a la API de integración que te de la información de este.

Si no te facilitan una API para integrarte pues tendrás que currarte el script que formatee la información desde el formato que te la den, en estos casos puedes plantearte sincronizaciones de artículos cada 30 minutos si no son muchos, por ejemplo, si solo son 1000 artículos, todo esto depende de lo que tengas de este tercero, sin mas información no sabría decirte si quiera si esto es buena idéa.

Si lo que quieres es ajustar tus precios a la competencia automáticamente solo rastreando su sitio web, no lo considero buena idéa, pero si relacionas la url de su artículo con el tuyo podrías sencillamente cuando se cargue el artículo usar curl para leer la página del tercero (corres el riego de que si se de cuenta te fastidie colocando sleeps y cosas por el estilo).

Si facilitas información como te retorna el tercero los datos se te podría dar una ayuda mas concreta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta detallada. Se trata de un proyecto web, con programa de afiliados, trabajando con links brindados por los proveedores como Amazon, Alibaba, Booking.com, etc. En productos como amazon, ellos me brindan la dirección para enlazar en mi sitio, pero esta no me mostrará los precios. Entonces quisiera que al mostrarse el producto el precio que muestra dependa del precio actual en la página de origen. Espero haber explicado bien la idea. Estoy disponible cualquier consulta. Nuevamente, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Tu buscas algo como esto  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html  y tendrías que tirar de API del proveedor, pero aunque la api te lo permita no puedes consultar 5 soaps al cargar la página, ya que cada carga va a relentizar el sitio de un modo enorme suma todos los tiempos de consulta a un tercero. luego estas APIs dependiendo del proveedor te permitirán o no, ya tendrías que leerte cada una de ellas, Amazon por ejemplo tiene algunas consultas, pero el resto ya no lo tengo tan claro.